# OrientDB connection pools

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm using OrientDB 2.2.5 for the backend for a multi threaded Java web application and I've tried numerous different connection methods. Each method seems to have a problem.

I essentially need something that I can call concurrently to use the OrientDB database, be it a static method or object instance.

I've tried various methods and had issues with record locking, or various other exceptions. The documentation shows a depreciated connection pool method (`ODatabaseDocumentPool`), and various other sources on the internet show a mixtures of ways (`ODatabaseDocumentTx`, `OPartitionedDatabasePool`).

Please could someone provide a reusable method for connecting to the instance (currently just a plocal) and issuing a basic query. Please also include any connection cleanup logic (I think it's this that has caused me issues with records being locked, even several seconds after the last update).

Any help/ pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To work with a recyclable pool of instances with minimum 1, maximum 10 instances:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/temp/mydb").setupPool(1, 10);
```

Once the factory is configured you can get a Graph instance to start working. OrientGraphFactory has 2 methods to retrieve a Transactional and Non-Transactional instance:

```
OrientGraph txGraph = factory.getTx();

OrientGraphNoTx noTxGraph = factory.getNoTx();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but somehow this is valid for one thread only. You can not maintain that outside in a different thread. So basically have factory initialized globally and use 'getTx()' does not work and reports that instance is closed. `Documentation:  The OrientDB is thread safe, the ODatabase* and OrientGraph* instances are not thread-safe.`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the document API, `OPartitionedDatabasePool` is the pool of your choice. Note that this is the pool implementation used internally by `OrientGraphFactory`.